# Gmaps4rails issue, perhaps incompatibilty with gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-4, gmaps4rails

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vh4gB.png

When I am trying to enter in reports (at about the 1:19 mark of the [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R0l-7en3dUw&feature=youtu.be)), they are just showing up as blank (see image above).  When I try to edit them, the edit page shows blank fields.  What could be causing this issue?  I named my model "Report" as opposed to User, but otherwise followed the tutorial to a T.  Below is my gemfile, thanks for any help you can give :)

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.4'

gem 'devise'
gem 'protected_attributes'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.2'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

gem 'geocoder'

gem 'gmaps4rails'

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

EDIT: Code for Reports Controller

```
class ReportsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_report, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /reports
  # GET /reports.json
  def index
    @reports = Report.all
  end

  # GET /reports/1
  # GET /reports/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /reports/new
  def new
    @report = Report.new
  end

  # GET /reports/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /reports
  # POST /reports.json
  def create
    @report = Report.new(report_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @report.save
        format.html { redirect_to @report, notice: 'Report was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @report }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @report.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /reports/1
  # PATCH/PUT /reports/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @report.update(report_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @report, notice: 'Report was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @report.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /reports/1
  # DELETE /reports/1.json
  def destroy
    @report.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to reports_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_report
      @report = Report.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def report_params
      params.require(:report).permit(:latitude, :longitude, :address, :description, :photo, :title, :text)
    end
end
```

Comment: Add more relevant code, gem file doesn't give hints towards problem.

Comment: @user3174983 Please share the code of `ReportsController` in the question.

Comment: there is no code for gmaps4rails in what you present.

Comment: moreover gmaps4rails doesnt touch any of your server side stuff now (except if you rely on the json builder).

Comment: All of the code I posted is generated from the video tutorial.  I am trying to make a map for reporting issues, and combine it with user sign in from Devise.  I'm not sure why, but by 1:18 in the tutorial video, the reports are blank after data is input.  Is this a known issue of combining this gem with other gems?  Sorry, I am a beginner at this.

Comment: seems you dont pass data to geocoder or something. You've not reached the part where gmaps4rails is used